# Why I am getting two different outputs while using unsigned int and unsigned long int in C++

Tags: c++

I have solved [UVa 100 - The 3n + 1 problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) and I come up with this solution

```
//UVa 100 - The 3n + 1 problem
//1.3 1st problem

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#define SIZE 1234567
using namespace std;



int main(void) {

    int i = 1, j = 1000000;

    int arr[SIZE] = {0};

    unsigned int n = 0, temp_i = i, temp_j = j, res = 0, max = 0;

    while(temp_i <= temp_j) {
        n = temp_i;
        res = 1;
        while( n != 1 ) {
            if(n % 2 == 0) {
                n = n >> 1;             
                res += 1;
            }
            else {
                n = 3 * n + 1;
                n = n >> 1;
                res += 2; 
            }
        } 

        arr[temp_i] = res;

        ++temp_i; 
    }

    while( scanf("%d %d",&i,&j) != EOF ) {      
        temp_j = j;
        temp_i = i;
        if( i > j )
            i = ( i + j ) - ( j = i );
        max = 0;
        for(; i <= j; ++i)
            if(max < arr[i])
                max =  arr[i];      

        printf("%u %u %u\n",temp_i,temp_j,max);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

okay everything is fine here but when I use

```
unsigned long int
```

or

```
unsigned long long int
```

in place of

```
unsigned int
```

I am getting errors or wrong result.
Here is one example

run this code and give value

```
626331 626331
```

now in the above program you will get (Which is correct)

```
374
```

as the answer while when you change unsigned int with unsigned long int or unsigned long long int you will get (which is wrong)

```
509
```

as the answer and I am totally confused why I am getting this value :(

PS: I am careful of format specifier and tried cin / cout too in place of scanf / printf but no luck.

Comment: Strange that you get correct result only with the smaller type. But anyway thats sounds as if you're exceeding the available number ranges. Try to trace relevant values.

Comment: `i = ( i + j ) - ( j = i );` This exhibits undefined behavior. An operation reading the value of an object is unsequenced with an operation modifying the same object.

Comment: How while I am tracing for the same number. Like I trace for 626331 the result is different and it is not exceeding the range :(

Comment: i = ( i + j ) - ( j = i) it is swapping two numbers and also I just tried changing it with temp_swap = i;   i = j;  j = temp_swap;  but still no luck still wrong result lgor

Comment: I suspect 509 is in fact the correct answer. The calculation for 626331 reaches `4,814,855,458` around step 106 (and then goes higher still), which overflows a 32-bit integer but not a 64-bit one. The calculations using `unsigned int` are completely bogus from that point on.

Comment: @geeksoul The infamous `3n+1` problem at UVA! The question spec tell you that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer, while some of their cases do indeed overflow. Their solution output was likely produced by a program with this faulty assumption. You are right, they are wrong. Move on to the next problem :)

Comment: To make the question more specific: it seems the important part is the width of `n`.  Changing the other variables declared on the same line doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I think you are right Igor, 509 should be the correct answer cause 626331 is a big number and somewhere in this program it should overflow the unsigned int. So my standard solution which I was comparing with my other solution is wrong and using unsigned long int or unsigned long long int is a good idea?

Comment: @Pradhan you are right

Comment: @geeksoul: `long int` in Windows is 32-bit

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry I don't understand :( please elaborate :)

Comment: I am using Linux @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: I am totally agree and now thinking that my assumption to take unsigned long int over unsigned int is not wrong indeed it is right